# KeyPress event not responding to some keys (up, down, left, right, home...)

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

I have a windows form and an OnKeyPress function. I also have KeyPreview turned on.

The function responds to most keys except up, down, left, right, home, pgdown, end and so on...

It's like whenever I press those keys, it doesn't send them to the form, it just toggles between the buttons and the other controls.

Anyone experienced that and can help out?

Comment: By design.  Override the ProcessCmdKey() method to see those keystrokes.

Comment: Have you tried OnKeyUp or OnKeyDown?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253412/basic-winform-keydown-event-handling)

Comment: Do you have a code snippet of what you have perhaps you are not capturing the corrct key code..

Answer (score 6):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)

> The KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys; however, the noncharacter keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events.

Comment: What's the cleanest way of processing in sequence a mixture of different types of keystrokes, if one will need the conversion from keycodes to characters that's normally part of KeyPress?

Comment: Right, but is there a reason that up/down/left/right all return KeyCode as 18?

Comment: @supercat, I'm not sure I understood Your question right. What exactly do You mean?

Comment: Awhile ago I tried to write a terminal-emulation-style program, which was supposed to send characters in response to arrow keys.  I ended up sending non-arrow keystrokes from KeyPress, and arrows from KeyDown, but that really seemed pretty ugly since I'm not sure KeyPress and KeyDown events will always be sequenced with respect to each other.

Comment: Explaination - I have the function "private void Form_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)". But e.KeyValue is always 18 whenever I press the arrow keys. (Gives different value for home, pgdown and the rest which is good) EDIT : Same goes for the Enter key. whenever he is pressed, e.KeyValue is also 18...

Comment: @supercat, they should be sequenced. MSDN says the same and I haven't met the situaton when it failed.

Comment: Oh, Than that means it doesn't respond to up/down/left/right. (Alt key is b/c my application is fullscreen so I gotta minimize it)